# Selection for editing through Scene Collections

Tags: selection-tools, collections

[image]

Now I want to select the choose objects for editing. I can select all the object in the scene (as in the screenshot below, through button A).

[image]

**How can I select only those objects that I have selected through the collections menu in the same way?**

Comment: Hello :). It's not very clear what you're asking. When you select objects in outliner, they're also selected in the viewport.

Comment: Hello =). When I select objects in the viewport they are selected as in screenshot 1. And I want to select them as in screenshot 2.